# .php file for woocommerce edit category?

Tags: plugins, php, categories, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

Can anyone help me find the .php file for editing a category page? I can't find it anywhere in the FTP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend entirely on your theme. Refer to the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview) and follow, from the left, the "Category Archive" path until you see a file that exists in your theme. That will be the file being used on the category pages. Keep in mind that if it is archive.php or index.php then it could also be being used for the other queries that lead to, so check the other files in the theme directory against the hierarchy to make sure you're not changing pages you don't want to.

For WooCommerce it's more complicated. Your theme could have its own file, or it could just be using the ones in WooCommerce. Refer to the [WooCommerce Template Structure](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) to see which template files WooCommerce uses. If you don't find what you're looking for refer to the WooCommerce [Theming Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/theming/) for documentation of customising and developing themes for WooCommerce.